# Integration $\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: integration

I have the following statement in a course for visual computing. 
integrating $\vec{v}(\vec{x}): \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$,
starting from $\vec{x}_{0}$, gives a curve $\vec{c}(t) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$

To be honest I dont know what this is exactly. Wondered if someone could give me a hint or point me in a direction. I only have calc 1 and dont know much about integrating vector functions

Comment: It's hard to say without more context, but probably what the given statement is getting at is that for nice vector fields $\bf v$, there is a unique curve $c(t)$ whose velocity vector coincides with the vector field each each point, that is, $c'(t) = {\bf v}(c(t))$ for all times $t$, starting at a given point, that is, satisfying $c(t_0) = {\bf x}_0$.

Comment: I *think* this is talking about what are called *integral curves* of a vector field, but as @Travis says, it's very hard to tell without more context.

Comment: This (parameterized or unparameterized) curve is called an *integral curve* of the vector field $\bf v$, and the image of the curve is also called a *flow line* of $\bf v$.